# Resizing a JPanel inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, cardlayout

I am new to Java, started learning swing and have a problem with resizing a JPanel inside a JFrame. I am following this tutorial:

http://vincentramdhanie.blogspot.com/2009/11/cardlayout-with-netbeans.html

because ultimately I am learning each of the different layouts and have come to the CardLayout now. In the above, there is a JPanel being used for a status panel. That is what I want to do as well, but when I drag a JPanel onto my blank JForm it takes up all the space and I don't see any resizing handles for it like I would if I were using a .NET panel. Changing preferredSize in the properties window also does nothing. What am I missing here? I feel like a complete noob for asking such a basic question but I really can't find any way to resize this thing..  :-|

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention; I am using NetBeans IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't resize the `JComponent` because you've select `CardLayout`. The `CardLayout` can holds/manages one or more components that share the same display space.

What you need to read [documentation and good tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Yes, I see now that what I am supposed to do is add a panel and set that panel's layout to CardLayout.. not the main JForm.. got it, thanks..